# Ordering a Yajra DataTable by created_at column in Laravel

Tags: php, yajra-datatable

I am trying to order a DataTable by the created_at column, but when I use the orderBy() method in the query function, the order is lost when the table is rendered. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Here is the code for my CustomerDataTable class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\Treatment;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder as HtmlBuilder;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class CustomerDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param QueryBuilder $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable
     */
    public function dataTable(QueryBuilder $query): EloquentDataTable
    {
        return (new EloquentDataTable($query))
            ->addColumn('created_at', function ($customer) {
                return $customer->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
            })
            ->addColumn('user', function ($customer) {
                $select = '<select class="form-control select2" onchange="changeUser(this.value, ' . $customer->id . ')">';
                $select .= '<option value="">Seçilmedi</option>';
                foreach (User::where('role', 'user')->get() as $user) {
                    $select .= '<option value="' . $user->id . '" ' . ($customer->user_id == $user->id ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $user->name . '</option>';
                }
                return $select;
            })
            ->addColumn('status', function ($customer) {
                $select = '<select class="form-control select2" onchange="changeStatus(this.value, ' . $customer->id . ')">';
                $select .= '<option value="">Seçilmedi</option>';
                foreach (Status::all() as $status) {
                    $select .= '<option value="' . $status->id . '" ' . ($customer->status_id == $status->id ? 'selected' : '') . '><span style="color: ' . $status->color . ' !important;">' . $status->title . '</span></option>';
                }
                return $select;
            })
            ->addColumn('treatment', function ($customer) {
                $select = '<select class="form-control select2" onchange="changeTreatment(this.value, ' . $customer->id . ')">';
                $select .= '<option value="">Seçilmedi</option>';
                foreach (Treatment::all() as $treatment) {
                    $select .= '<option value="' . $treatment->id . '" ' . ($customer->treatment_id == $treatment->id ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $treatment->title . '</option>';
                }
                return $select;
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($customer) {
                $btn = '<a href="' . route('customer.edit', $customer) . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Düzenle</a>';
                if (auth()->user()->role != 'user'):
                    $btn .= '&nbsp;';
                    $btn .= '<form action="' . route('customer.destroy', $customer) . '" method="post" class="d-inline-block">
                        ' . csrf_field() . '
                        ' . method_field('DELETE') . '
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="return confirm(\'Silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?\')">Sil</button>
                    </form>';
                endif;
                return $btn;
            })
            ->setRowId('id')
            ->rawColumns(['user', 'status', 'treatment', 'action']);
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Customer $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(Customer $model, Request $request): QueryBuilder
    {
        if (auth()->user()->role == 'user') {
            $model = $model->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        }

        if ($request->category_id) {
            $model = $model->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
        }

        if ($request->user_id) {
            $model = $model->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
        }

        if ($request->min_date && $request->max_date) {
            $model = $model->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->min_date . ' 00:00:00', $request->max_date . ' 23:59:59']);
        }

        if ($request->treatment_id) {
            $model = $model->where('treatment_id', $request->treatment_id);
        }

        if ($request->status_id) {
            $model = $model->where('status_id', $request->status_id);
        }

        if ($request->country_id) {
            $model = $model->where('country_id', $request->country_id);
        }

        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html(): HtmlBuilder
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->setTableId('customer-table')
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->dom(auth()->user()->role == 'user' ? 'lfrtip' : 'Blfrtip')
            ->orderBy(1)
            ->selectStyleSingle()
            ->language([
                'url' => '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.4/i18n/tr.json'
            ])
            ->lengthMenu([10, 25, 50, 100, 500])
            ->pageLength(25)
            ->buttons([
                Button::make('copy')->text('<i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Kopyala')->exportOptions([
                    'columns' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                ]),
                Button::make('excel')->text('<i class="fa fa-file"></i> Excel')->exportOptions([
                    'columns' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                ]),
                Button::make('csv')->text('<i class="fa fa-file-zip-o"></i> CSV')->exportOptions([
                    'columns' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                ]),
                Button::make('pdf')->text('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF')->exportOptions([
                    'columns' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                ]),
                Button::make('print')->text('<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Yazdır')->exportOptions([
                    'columns' => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                ]),
            ])
            ->parameters([
                'drawCallback' => 'function() {
                    $(".select2").select2({
                        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
                    });
                }',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the dataTable columns definition.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make('id')
                ->title('ID')
                ->addClass('align-middle')
                ->orderable(),
            Column::computed('created_at')
                ->title('Kayıt Tarihi')
                ->addClass('align-middle')
                ->orderable(),
            Column::computed('user')
                ->title('Danışman')
                ->addClass('align-middle'),
            Column::make('name')
                ->title('Adı')
                ->addClass('align-middle'),
            Column::make('phone')
                ->title('Telefon')
                ->addClass('align-middle'),
            Column::computed('status')
                ->title('Durum')
                ->addClass('align-middle')
                ->orderable(),
            Column::computed('treatment')
                ->title('Tedavi')
                ->addClass('align-middle')
                ->orderable(),
            Column::computed('action')
                ->title('İşlem')
                ->exportable(false)
                ->printable(false)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename(): string
    {
        return 'Customer_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

I have tried using the orderBy() method in the query() function, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the ordering of the table. The table is always displayed in the order that the data was retrieved from the database.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: I dont know the answer, but is this a clue `return $this->builder()->orderBy(1)` Would this cause the DataTable to resort the data you give it. If you made that `->orderBy(2)` would it do as requred, or remove that sort entirely

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already tried this but it never fetches the most recent data as created_at

Answer (score 0):

just try change

```
->addColumn('created_at', function ($customer) {
                return $customer->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
            })
```

to be

```
->editColumn('created_at', function ($customer) {
                return $customer->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
            })
```

it is work for me
also if you want get the latest just change the ordering on function html()

```
->orderBy(1,'desc')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35328077)